# \centering leads to cascade of errors

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes, expansion, programming

Context: I'm developing a title page (writing my own `titlepage` environment) and I'm writing my own `\thanks` command (to give me control over where I spew the footnotes). Not knowing how `\footnote` does this, I decided to write each footnote's text out to a file (using the `newfile package` to manage I/O) and then later read from that file into a `tabular` to format the hanging footnotes.

I ran into problems (various errors and a badly formatted tabular for the second and later footnotes). In developing an MWE to explain the problem, I discovered to my shock that simply commenting out a `\centering` command caused it to work perfectly.

Why is `\centering` causing the cascade of errors? How can I retain `\centering` and still get the desired functionality and output format?

In the following MWE, I draw your attention/scrutiny to `\storeTitle` and `\printTitle` because I harbor some suspicion about how I pass the argument `#1` from `\storeTitle` to `\printTitle` (and whether the expansion(s) is/are appropriate). (I realize the redefining of `\printTitle` may seem circuitous. Specifying a title is optional. If you don't call `\storeTitle`, then `\printTitle` remains empty and nothing happens there.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfile}
\newoutputstream{mystream}% Creates file stream for footnotes for title page
\openoutputfile{\jobname.mystream}{mystream}

\newcommand{\printTitle}{}
\newcommand{\storeTitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\printTitle}{{\large#1}}}

\newcounter{ntpfootnote}
\newcommand*{\fnmark}{\textit{\textsuperscript{\alph{ntpfootnote}}}}
\newcommand{\rowForTabular}[1]{\fnmark & #1 \\}
\newcommand{\mythanks}[1]{%
    \addtocounter{ntpfootnote}{1}%  Increments footnote counter
    {\fnmark}% Prints formatted footnote mark
%   Adds to output stream a row of text to become a row of the tabular representing the footnotes
    \addtostream{mystream}{\rowForTabular{#1}}   
}

\storeTitle{Some title\mythanks{with a first footnote.} and also a second footnote.\mythanks{This is the second footnote.}}
\begin{document}

%\centering% Uncomment this line to induce failure
\printTitle
\closeoutputstream{mystream}
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}%
    {p{8pt} p{5.5in}|}%
    \input{\jobname.mystream}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The output (uncentered, but otherwise as desired) is:
[image]

If I then uncomment the `\centering` command, I get a bunch of errors citing the location of `\printTitle`:

- Argument of `\@firstoftwo` has an extra `}`.
- Runaway argument? Paragraph ended before `\@firstoftwo` was complete.
- Missing `\endcsname` inserted.
- Argument of `\@argdef` has an extra `}`.
- …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "cascade" of errors you mention are consequences of the first. TeX, as a macro expansion language, struggles to recover from errors, so one error can possibly induce much more.

The error happens with `\centering` because it redefines `\\`, which is expanded when written to the file, and the new definition breaks when expanded in that context.

To fix the issue you can `\protect` the `\\` to avoid its expansion when writing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfile}
\newoutputstream{mystream}% Creates file stream for footnotes for title page
\openoutputfile{\jobname.mystream}{mystream}

\newcommand{\printTitle}{}
\newcommand{\storeTitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\printTitle}{{\large#1}}}

\newcounter{ntpfootnote}
\newcommand*{\fnmark}{\textit{\textsuperscript{\alph{ntpfootnote}}}}
\newcommand{\rowForTabular}[1]{\fnmark & #1 \protect\\}% <- \protect here
\newcommand{\mythanks}[1]{%
    \addtocounter{ntpfootnote}{1}%  Increments footnote counter
    {\fnmark}% Prints formatted footnote mark
%   Adds to output stream a row of text to become a row of the tabular representing the footnotes
    \addtostream{mystream}{\rowForTabular{#1}}% <- Here
}

\storeTitle{Some title\mythanks{with a first footnote.} and also a second footnote.\mythanks{This is the second footnote.}}
\begin{document}

\centering% Uncomment this line to induce failure
\printTitle
\closeoutputstream{mystream}
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}%
    % {p{8pt} p{5.5in}|}%
    {p{8pt} p{\dimexpr\textwidth-8pt-4\tabcolsep}|}% <- Suggestion
    \input{\jobname.mystream}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

You also had an extra space after the `\addtostream` command, which was enlarging the space after the footnote.

Also, I suggested a way to avoid the overfull `\hbox` from your table.

Comment: Thanks! I never would have guessed that `\centering` would have redefined \\ and/or that that would have caused a problem. Just as a lesson for the future, is `\protect`ing such a use of `\\` something that a seasoned LaTeX programmer would do just by instinct and prudence? Or would one need to think that many moves ahead to decide to do that? (I'm a chess player, hence the analogy)

Comment: All the alignment command redefine ``\\`` (this is one of the reasons why ``\\`` shouldn't be used to break lines in normal text flow), see around line 620 of [`ltmiscen.dtx`](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/master/base/ltmiscen.dtx). You need to `\protect` fragile commands (which can't full expand safely) in full expansion contexts, such as inside an `\edef` or a `\write`. Some commands are known to be fragile and always need to be protected, some are discovered when they break. One common case is a fragile command inside a `\caption` (which `\write`s to the `.lof` file).